# Using an ArrayList of objects in Java (Processing)

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

I have created the following sketch in Processing (Java):

```
ArrayList<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  pieces.add(new Piece(100, 200)); // I ADD ONE PIECE TO THE ARRAY LIST 
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < pieces.size(); i++) {
    Piece p = pieces.get(i);
    p.display(); // I WANT TO DRAW THE PIECE I'VE CREATED IN SETUP()
  }
}

class Piece {
  int x;
  int y;

  Piece (int x, int y) {
    x = x;
    y = y;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(x, y, 30, 30); // AS X IS 100 AND Y IS 200, A BALL SHOULD BE DRAWN AT THOSE COORDINATES, BUT INSTEAD THE BALL IS DRAWN AT 0,0. WHY THAT?
  }
}
```

I add one piece to the array list which has coordinates (100,200). When I execute p.display() it draws the ellipse at 0,0 and not at 100,200. Why does this happen?

Comment: Where is `ellipse` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe

```
x = x;
y = y;
```

should be

```
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
```

in your Piece() constructor.  x=x just sets the value to itself, using the `this` keyword will set your Piece's values according to the ones you are trying to pass in.

Comment: @DavidDejori You should accept the answer if that solves your question. :)